# Having trouble implementing "jump to slide" in a jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying this for the past 2 days and can't seem to figure out a solution..

I have the prev and next arrows working for navigation (along with arrow keys). But now that I have a timeline, I can't seem to 'jump to' slides using a div-id (correctly)?

So for example, if I wanted to go from section 1 to section 5, I want to be able to click on my section 5 button and it jumps to that slide.

**[Here is my working example](https://preview.hs-sites.com/_hcms/preview/template/multi?template_layout_id=3792192176&is_buffered_template_layout=true&portalId=494351&tc_deviceCategory=DESKTOP#target-3)**. The slider's timeline appears on slide 2+. For the example, I am only working within the target section.

This is the code I am using to "jump to a slide":

```
$('.slideshow-timeline a').click(function() {
    var target_id = $(this).attr('href');
    removeClasses();
    $($(".tour-panel")[current]).addClass("fadeOutRight");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(target_id).addClass("active-tour fadeInLeft");
    }, 50);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $($(".tour-panel")[current]).removeClass("fadeOutRight");
    }, 750);
    current = target_id.split('-')[1] || 0;
});
```

But for some reason, I get 2 specific problems:

> Problem 1: I click to go to a slide, then use arrow keys to go back ~ this causes me to jump back 2 slides.

---

> Problem 2: I click to go to a slide, then use arrow keys to go forward ~ this breaks my slider and shows a white screen

I believe the majority of the probelem lies within this line of code:

`current = target_id.split('-')[1] || 0;`

But I am not 100% sure and need your help, I have prepared a very basic fiddle example **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/gjyswrr9/)**.

---

Some things I've tried was messing with the `split()` variables, swapping out `nextElement();` and `previousElement();` and I just can not find a solution that works.

All help is very appreciated!

## Links to certain files

[Pastebin to full JS](http://pastebin.com/D2pHdDT6)

[Pastebin to full CSS](http://pastebin.com/B91f1veY)

Comment: could you make a JS fiddle with the bug ?

Comment: @Blag There is one [in place](https://jsfiddle.net/gjyswrr9/) with the basic functionality. I can include a pastebin link to my full JS as well.

Comment: `<a href="#target-1">Tracking</a>` => tracking is under `#target-2` and same for others, every link is not good...

Comment: Is this in relation to the Fiddle or working example? Since the working example is on a framework, it's hard to recreate it in a fiddle.

I will try and make a more clear fiddle

Comment: So just to clarify, your slider is working perfectly with mouse clicks but it is when you use to the arrow keys for navigation that it is messing up? Because both the working example and jsfiddle seem to be working for me when I click random slide buttons - I am able to jump to those slides.

Comment: @AndyNoelker The slider works if you use **only** arrow keys or clicking on the side tabs. It's when you add a click onto the timeline, the DOM doesn't know what to do, and forgets what place it's on. It doesn't count up the same spectrum between the 3 options.

Comment: @ether okay, now I am seeing some more weird behavior. Will investigate.

Comment: @AndyNoelker Thanks! It's a weird glitch but unfortunately, it catastrophically breaks the slider. :(

Answer (score 3):

Check out that fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gjyswrr9/19/

Problems were in 3 places:

```
var previous = parseInt(current, 10) - 1;
var next = parseInt(current) + 1;
```

(they were strings, not ints).

And

```
current = target_id.split('-')[1] - 1 || 0;
```

(you count links starting with 1)

Hope it works as you need.

Comment: Now the `var previous` and `var next` are you talking about replacing the `vars` in the `previousIndex()` and `nextIndex()` functions? **EDIT**: Just updated the working example, but still seem to have the same problems

Comment: @ether Regarding your question - yes, they are from previousIndex and nextIndex functions. Did you check out fiddle? Does it work?

Comment: I did notice that, updated my live example and now I can click through the bottom links to navigate. But if I use the `<` or `>` or the arrow keys to further navigate, it still jumps around, or breaks the slider.

Comment: @ether I see that in your live example it's minified. May this be the issue? Maybe you should delete your old file and make sure that system uses the new one? Or turn off minification to debug?

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the framework, it automatically minifies JS.

Comment: As you already discussed above, something is probably messed up with markup. Assuming, you have what you have now, could you change and try: 
setTimeout(function() {
  $(g).addClass("active-tour fadeInRight")
}, 50)

instead of 

$($(".tour-panel")[f]).addClass("active-tour fadeInRight") 

in $(".slideshow-timeline a").click(function() {

Comment: What are you defining `g` as? `[current]`?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go -> [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gjyswrr9/22/)

What I've basicly changed is your `current` value, which you are defining in your click function. Actually, your `id` value is a string, so firing `nextElement()` won't change the value, instead it will concatenate it. This results in some weird behaviour, so instead of changing from target `0` to `1`, you just change from `0` to `01`.

Also I've adjusted your `$('.slideshow-timeline a').click(function() { }` to behave the same way as your `nextElement()` function does.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention

> I believe the majority of the probelem lies within this line of code:
>
> ```
> current = target_id.split('-')[1] || 0;
> ```

You've been right with this. As mentioned above, `target_id.split('-')[1]` will return you a string value, not a number and this again, as mentioned above, leads to the weird behaivour where your code just concatenates your returned string with a number. To achieve the goal you want, you have to parse `target_id.split('-')[1]`'s value into a `number` value by using JavaScripts built-in `parseInt()` function.

The result is the following:

```
current = parseInt(target_id.split('-')[1]) || 0;
```

Comment: After implementing your idea into the working model, we still have a few issues.
Clicking a link in the timeline will take you to the link-1 (ie: If i click custom lists, it takes me to segmentation). Additionally, clicking a section title like "optimize" returns me to the tour home.

Comment: Did you change currents order in your function? And do you also parse your string into an int, as mentioned in my edit?

Comment: As in change the current order, do you mean adding it into the `setTimeout` function for `('.slideshow-timeline a')`?

Comment: Take a look at this http://pastebin.com/vCerDb9D. Actually, you only have to change this line `current = parseInt(target_id.split('-')[1]) || 0;`. First, you  pull it up just right before the execution of your `setTimeout()`, so it uses your new `current` value. And then, right into the same line, you put your current evaluation into a `parseInt()` function. And this should do the whole trick. Let me know if it works and if not, you may share your current HTML/JS? Just the slider part would be fine. :)

Comment: Damn, I really wish I could have come back and said it worked, but still nothing. I will try my best to separate you some HTML. [current js here](http://pastebin.com/FjdaQLzS) Since the framework is built using modules, there is a lot of extra `containers` but this is the code I am using to build a single slide: [single slide html](http://pastebin.com/YH70QRrE).

Comment: Your JS part seems to be fine. Not sure if you've messed up anything in your HTML or if you're using any minification tools breaking up your code. At least - Did my example (I mean my little fiddle) work properly, as you are expecting of your own page?

Comment: Seems to be correct, I just want to make sure everything is working before accepting an answer. The one issue at hand that I don't believe to be due to minifying is that if I click a section title, it takes me to home, instead of that section.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Can you please check the below link..

Is this what you are looking for right?

Please refer this link 
    [jsFiddle][1]

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/gjyswrr9/39/
```

Script code as below,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var current = 0;

function previousIndex() {
var previous = parseInt(current,10) - 1;
if(previous == 0) {
    previous = $(".tour-panel").size();
}
return previous;
}

function nextIndex() {
var next = parseInt(current,10) + 1;
if(next == $(".tour-panel").size()+1) {
next = 1;
}
return next;
}

function removeClasses() {
$(".tour-panel").each(function(index) {
if(index != current) {
  $(this).removeClass("active-tour fadeInRight fadeInLeft fadeOutRight fadeOutLeft");
}
})
}

function nextElement() {
removeClasses(); 
current = nextIndex();
setTimeout(function() {
$("#target-"+current).addClass("active-tour fadeInRight");
 }, 50);
 }

function previousElement() {
removeClasses();
current = previousIndex();
setTimeout(function() {
$("#target-"+current).addClass("active-tour fadeInLeft");  
}, 50);
setTimeout(function() {
$($(".tour-panel")[nextIndex()]).removeClass("active-tour fadeOutRight");
}, 750);
}


$('.slideshow-timeline a').click(function() {
  var target_id = $(this).attr('href');
removeClasses();
$($(".tour-panel")[current]).addClass("fadeOutRight");
setTimeout(function() {
    $(target_id).addClass("active-tour fadeInLeft");
}, 50);
setTimeout(function() {
    $($(".tour-panel")[current]).removeClass("fadeOutRight");
}, 750);
current = target_id.split('-')[1] || 0;
});


Mousetrap.bind('left', previousElement);
Mousetrap.bind('right', nextElement);

$(".previous").click(previousElement);
$(".next").click(nextElement);
});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11282545)

Comment: ok i will edit the answer and add the code part too.. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Once bringing this into the dev environment, it still causes a jump in the slides because it is counting the `index` of the slides using the timeline separately from the `index` of the slides using the arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

You were right... the problem was in this line:

```
current = target_id.split('-')[1] || 0;
```

try this:

```
current = (target_id.split('-')[1] - 1) || 0; // cater for zero-index
```

**UPDATE**

- On further investigation, I discovered a few things on your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gjyswrr9/) (12-Feb-16):
  the 'li's for 'Connect', 'Convert' and 'Optimize' are outside of the 'ul' above - I'm guessing that's where they should be.
- The ids for the 'li's mentioned above don't follow your naming convention ("target-1", "target-2", etc). That will sure cause the strategy employed here to fail.
- There should be matching 'div' elements for each 'li'... in your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gjyswrr9/), elements for the aforementioned 'li's are missing.

Cleared up some of the issues with this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zcakeczb/5/).